# Finding a UIImage file type

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, mobile

Is there a way to determine what file type was used to create a UIImage?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Does it really matter what type the original image was? Can you implement whatever you want by inspecting the details of the underlying `CGImageRef` object (property is called `CGImage`) for alpha component information, etc?

For more details lookup the documentation for `CGImage` from the `UIImage` manual page.

Comment: Yes, it matters if you're trying to take a UIImage and turn it into a file and need to know which format the data is in.

Answer (score 2):

Nope!

If this is for images you've loaded yourself you could store that association somewhere else instead. If the file is from elsewhere then it may not even have come from a file in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

If the image is add using the imagePickerController you can determine the type in your image picker delegate method as follows:

```
- (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker 
didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info {

    // Get the image reference URL
    NSURL *referenceURL = [info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerReferenceURL];

    // The path extension contains the image type: JPG, PNG, GIF, etc.
    NSString *originalImageType = referenceURL.pathExtension; 

}
```